# Can I view my follower's items out of a game?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can I view my follower's gear when I'm not in a game?  It's pretty annoying to shop for my merc's gear in the AH without being able to see it quickly...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You can view not only your character's equipment, but also your followers with the online profile.  Your online profile is at `http://us.battle.net/d3/en/profile/<battle tag name>-<battle tag #>/`, and from there, you can navigate to each of your characters.  At the bottom of your character screen will be your followers, including the gear that is equipped on them.  Below is an example of one of my followers (don't judge):

[image: Follower section]

It may not give the best information, and it may not be 100% up to date, but it's pretty much the only option you have for a second screen.

Comment: Addendum: this assumes you're an English player on the US servers.  Modify the URL for other areas/languages.

Comment: Cool, better than nothing!

Comment: I would add that you can't get to this URL unless you've set up a profile first-- go to diablo III home page, log in, then click on your profile and go to manage profiles... took a while to find it...